# GraphicExtraLarge complication Apple watchOS and SwiftUI produces warning and being removed from the timeline

Tags: swiftui, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I've run into a warning for CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularView:

> The 'content' view on
> *TtGC17_ClockKit_SwiftUI52CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicExtraLargeCircularViewV21Target21GraphicExtraLargeView*
> took more than two frames to render. This template will be removed
> from the timeline.

This certainly issues my app from time to time, so bug needs to be caught.

Please help if you've seen something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no way to debug this without seeing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: unfortunately implementation chain is too long and I can't share code due to NDA, just hoping that someone has seen similar message before and found route-cause, thnx!